# Have an ImageView rotatable by dragging on it and find the angle of its rotation

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView (of say, a steering wheel) and want it to be rotated when the user places their finger on it (on the border) and drags along the intended direction of rotation. I also need to know by how many degrees it is rotated by (basically the magnitude of rotation). When the user releases it (is no longer touching the ImageView) it should slowly return back to its original position.

How is such a responsive rotating ImageView implementation possible?

Comment: Your question is far too broad, and I've flagged it for closure (only mods can do that when there's a bounty on the question). Please re-read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GauravMall The answer? I was talking about the question (the one you added an answer to). It wasn't a reply to you. Clear or not, it's still too broad without any code ("gimme the code" isn't considered a good, on-topic question)

Comment: @Zoe well, what would a better way to ask such a question be?

Comment: @ShlokJhawar well, if you want to ask it like this, you can't fix it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/6296561 (specifically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274665/6296561) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259950/6296561. You need to significantly narrow down the scope if you want this to be on-topic (because in its current state, this can be answered in extremely many ways).

Comment: @GauravMall you said "I don't thnk that the **answer** is broad". The question is broad by the definition of the close vote: "There are either too many possible answers, **or good answers would be too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." See the last link there ^

Comment: Actually, even better, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Questions like this also result in too many valid answers, falling under the definition of too broad

Comment: @GauravMall The thing is, if a mod agrees, the bounty is canceled and the question is (usually) closed (or at least opened for user closure). Takes a couple hours nowadays, but it does the trick.

Comment: @Zoe I understand you're trying to keep the community 'clean', but I'd appreciate it if you could wait a couple of days until I make progress on this project. :) After that, I don't mind what you do about this question

Comment: @ShlokJhawar [Not gonna happen.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/6296561)

Comment: @GauravMall not all questions get deleted, so not necessarily. But yeah, that's a risk. It's also a risk whenever you answer a question in general, even if it's on-topic. There's even been instances of the question asker deleting the question after getting answers (although they usually get undeleted if it's a decent enough question and the answer is worth it, but if it isn't). Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/6296561

Comment: @Zoe I found his answer helpful, just saying

Comment: same Questions please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881007/rotate-imageview-like-steering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want. If you want your "steering" to be rotated by its center you will need to add an axis in the center. If you want to do steering when your finger slides you will need to have two axis.

**Clarification:** By *Axis* I mean the touch listener you will implement.

It really depends on your implementation. But let's look at this example:

For instance, you have this steering:

[image: Steering Example]

So, you want to steer with an axis by the center. Basically, using the `onTouch()` function we can get the coordinates of what has happened. Using the `Math` module we will do some calculations using the `toDegrees()` function to convert some of our values into usable, and necessary degree values which then you can use to rotate an image-view. This is some sample code:

```
final float xc = wheel.getWidth() / 2;
final float yc = wheel.getHeight() / 2;
final float x = event.getX();
final float y = event.getY();
```

Then using the `MotionEvent` class, we can see if the touch was to the top, right, left, or bottom like this:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //For moving to the top(driving straight)
```

Because your question is too broad, I can't give a detailed code description, but here are some references:

1. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868
2. [Rotate Imageview like steering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881007/rotate-imageview-like-steering)
3. https://andygeeks.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-animate-image-to-rotate-with.html

Comment: same questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881007/rotate-imageview-like-steering

Comment: Yup, they are the same. But the answer was not very good, so why not improve the answer?

Comment: Yes, I have test the above link which I give on comment and it's working fine. more information @ Gaurav Mall your last link Look at :  https://andygeeks.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-animate-image-to-rotate-with.html

Comment: I have posted those links...Why are you commenting them again?